# Normality Assumption - Help!

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

I am relatively new to statistics and struggle with the normality assumption (where and how it needs to be assessed).
I understand that parametric tests need the data to be normally distributed. The literature seems to be conflicting information on what variables need to be checked.

Could someone suggest a normality-testing process to follow for t-tests, multiple regression and binary logistic regression in terms of what variables/things to check, when and how?

I am getting confused with the below:
Before conducting a parametric test:

1. Do I need to check that each continuous independent variable follows a normal distribution? Do I need to check the dependent variable also?
2. If any variables do not follow the Normal distribution, is it at this point that I would potentially transform data and restest/assess for normality?
3. Does any of the above apply to certain types of tests (e.g. t-tests)?
   After running a test:
4. Is it only the standardised residuals that need to be assessed for normality?
   Apologies if any of the above are silly questions!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I addressed the regression assumptions about normality in an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/576209/247274) a few days ago, and my objections to **A** and **B** apply to logistic regression, too.

Comment: Thanks Dave- just read your answer.  To check my understanding, I do not need to ensure any of my predictors have a normal distibution pre-testing?  Is an Ordinary Least Squares Regression applicable to all parametric testing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless) That page, and the many links from it, should answer all of your questions. It's only residuals that matter (think of t-tests as very simple regressions), and even then you don't absolutely need normal residuals. See presentations on [best linear unbiased estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Markov_theorem) and the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).